# Answer/Comment indicator

Tags: support

Is there a way to tell if there is an answer or comment on your answer?  This use to be done through an envelope icon.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the StackExchange logo at the top left. It lights up when you have responses on any SE site.

See also:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/